What is the mistake in this MIPS partition function?
I want to translate this function written in C into MIPS:
int partition(int f, int l) {
  int pivot = v[l];
  int i = f;

  for (int j = f; j < l; j++) 
    if (v[j] < pivot) 
      swap(i++,j);

  swap(i, l );
  return (i);
}

This is the code that I have written, when I run some test cases it returns nothing.
swap:                           # swap entry point
        sll $t0, $a0, 2         # make i into address
        sll $t1, $a1, 2         # make j into address
        
        la  $t2, v              # load vector address
        
        add $t3, $t2, $t0       # get address of v[i]
        add $t4, $t2, $t1       # get address of v[j]
        
        lw  $t5, 0($t3)         # get v[i]
        lw  $t6, 0($t4)         # get v[j]
        
        sw  $t5, 0($t4)         # set v[j] = v[i]
        sw  $t6, 0($t3)         # set v[i] = v[j]

        jr      $ra             # return to caller

partition:
        la  $t0, v              # load vector address
        
        add  $sp, $sp, -16      # pop 2 items from stack
        sw   $s0, 0($sp)
        sw   $s1, 4($sp)
        sw   $s2, 8($sp)
        sw   $s3, 12($sp)
        
        sll  $t2, $a1, 2        # make l into address
        add  $t3, $t0, $t2      # find address of v[l]
        lw   $s2, 0($t3)        # load v[l] into $s2 (pivot)

        add  $s0, $a0, $zero    # int ($s0) i = f
        
        add  $s1, $a0, $zero    # int ($s1) j = f
        
        add  $s3, $a1, $zero
        
Loop:                           # "for" loop
        slt  $t7, $s1, $s3      # check j < l
        beq  $t7, $zero, EndLoop # exit loop if j >= l
        
        sll  $t2, $s1, 2        # make j into address
        add  $t3, $t0, $t2      # find address of v[j]
        lw   $t5, 0($t3)        # load v[j] into $t5
        
        
        slt  $t6, $t5, $s2      # if (v[j] < pivot) set $t6 = 1
        beq  $t6, $zero, continueLoop 
        add  $a0, $s0, $zero
        add  $a1, $s1, $zero
        jal  swap
        
        addi $s0, $s0, 1        # i++
        
continueLoop:
        addi $s1, $s1, 1        # j++
        j    Loop               # go to start of Loop
        
EndLoop:
        
        add  $v0, $s0, $zero
        jr   $ra

I have tried everything, but I either get [Bad Memory Address] or nothing in return when I run the code mentioned above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For starters, the partition function is not preserving $ra.  Next, that function is not restoring the stack & s registers.

Thank you very much! After saving the $ra in the stack and restoring it upon ending the loop I was able to get the desired result! Thanks again!
